# Translate Part of a Line

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a bunch of files that I am moving from one wiki (Markdown based) to another (Creole based).  I have written a couple of sed scripts to things such as convert link formats and header formats.  But the new wiki allows a directory structure and I would rather use that than the pseudo-directory structure I have now.  I have already renamed the files, but I need to convert all of the links from `_` delimited to `/` delimited.

Basic info:

```
Creole link: [[url]] [[url|name]]
```

I only want to convert the links that do not contain a `.` or a `/`.

I would really appreciate if you explained what the command you give means so that I can learn from it.

---

### Sample

```
this is a line with a [[Link_to_something]] and [[Something_else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

to

```
this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

---

### What I have tried

`y///` only works on the whole line.

`s//\u\2` only supports case translations.

Comment: You'll get better answers  if you edit your question to include sample data that covers the cases you need to fix AND sample output for same. Good luck.

Comment: Those examples are a great help - they make what you're after much, much clearer than the description without the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'd use Perl.  It can be done as a one-liner, thus:

```
perl -pe 's{\[\[([^/.|]+)(|[^]]+)?\]\]}{$x=$1;$y=$2;$x=~s%_%/%g;"[[$x$y]]"}gex;' <<'EOF'
this is a line with a [[Link_to_something]] and [[Something_else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
EOF
```

The output from that is:

```
this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

Whether that's good style etc is entirely open to debate.

I'll explain this version of the code, which is isomorphic with the code above:

```
perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;
         while (my $line = <>)
         {
             $line =~ s{ \[\[ ([^/.|]+) (|[^]]+)? \]\] }
                       { my($x, $y) = ($1, $2); $x =~ s%_%/%g; "[[$x$y]]" }gex;
             print $line;
         } '
```

The `while` loop is basically what the `-p` provides in the first version.  I've explicitly named the input variable as `$line` instead of using the implicit `$_` as in the first version.  I also had to declare `$x` and `$y` because of the `use strict; use warnings;`.

The substitute command takes the form `s{pattern}{replace}` because there are slashes in the regexes themselves.  The `x` modifier allows (non-significant) spaces in the two parts, which makes it easier to lay out. The `g` modifier repeats the substitution as often as the pattern matches.  The `e` modifier says 'treat the right-hand part of the substitution as an expression'.

The matching pattern looks for a pair of open square brackets, then remembers a sequence of characters other than `/`, `.` or `|`, optionally followed by a `|` and a sequence of characters other than `]`, finishing at a pair of close square brackets.  The two captures are `$1` and `$2`.

The replacement expression saves the values of `$1` and `$2` in variables `$x` and `$y`.  It then applies a simpler substitution to `$x`, changing underscores into slashes.  Then the result value is the string of `[[$x$y]]`.  You can't modify `$1` or `$2` directly in the replacement expression. And the inner `s%_%/%g;` clobbers `$1` and `$2`, which is why I needed `$x` and `$y`.

There might be another way to do it - this is Perl, so TMTOWTDI: there's more than one way to do it.  But this does at least work.

Comment: Wow, perl is beautiful in the worst way.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
awk -vORS='' -vRS='[[][[][^].]*[]][]]' '{gsub(/_/,"/",RT);print $0 RT}' file
this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

- Set the output record separator to null
- Set the record separator to `[[...]]` (where the `...` does not contain a `.`.
- Replace all `_`'s in what is placed in the record separator variable `RT` with `/`'s
- Print the concatenated record and record separator. i.e. `$0 RT`

This is a sed solution:

```
sed 's/\[\[[^].]*]]/\a\n&\a\n/g' file |
sed '/^\[\[[^]]*\]\]\a/y/_/\//;H;$!d;g;s/\a\n//g;s/.//'
this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

- Surround `[[...]]`'s by `\a\n`'s N.B. `\a` is chosen as an unlikely character to appear in the file.
- Translate '`_`'s to `/`'s in lines beginning with `[[`
- Remove all occurrences of `\a\n`'s

If you have GNU sed, this will do:

```
sed '/\[\[[^].]*]]/{s||'\''$(sed "y/_/\\//" <<<"&")'\''|g;s/.*/echo '\''&'\''/}' file 
this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

Comment: Thanks, the trick with the sed one is I was not thinking about multiple commands.  (And I really need to learn awk)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`python`** to simplify the regex:

```
$ python3 -c '
> import re
> import sys
> for line in sys.stdin:
>     print(re.sub(r"\[\[(?!http).*?\]\]", lambda m:m.group(0).replace("_", "/"), line), end="")
> ' <input.txt

this is a line with a [[Link/to/something]] and [[Something/else|something else]]
this site is cool [[http://example.com/this_page]]
```

**Note**: `$ and >` at the beginning of lines are command prompt.

---

You can also do it in **`vim`** visually:

```
/\[\[\(http\)\@!.\{-}\]\]
:%s@@\=substitute(submatch(0), '_', '/', '')@g
```