# How to do substitution only on highlighted text in vim?

Tags: vim

Before doing substitution, I usually type <kbd>/foo</kbd> to search the pattern first.
Vim automatically highlight all strings match the pattern.
Then I figure out how to write the substitution command `:%s/foo/bar/g`.
When the pattern is complex, it's much harder to write the substitution command than the search command.
If I can do substitution only on highlighted strings. It becomes easy.

#### For example:

Question: [Translate Part of a Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438680/translate-part-of-a-line)
I can figure out the search pattern: **`/\[\[\(http\)\@!.\{-}\]\]`**
But I cannot figure out the substitution command easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitue with the visual selection in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105399/how-to-substitue-with-the-visual-selection-in-vim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the previously searched pattern if you use an empty string as the search pattern in the substitute command:

After `/foo` type `:%s//bar/g` in normal mode to replace "foo" by "bar".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'c' flag to tell Vim to confirm before replacing. It highlights and stops to ask before every match it finds to the given pattern.

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out:

```
:%s@@\=substitute(submatch(0), '_', '/', '')@g
```

But is there any better ways?