# How to substitue with the visual selection in Vim?

Tags: vim

I found substitue in vim has a  range parameter:

```
:[range]s/pattern/sring/[c]/[g]/[e]/[i]/[I]/[p]
```

But I'm wondering if it would be handy to let the substitution occur only in the visual selection.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could do that.

After visual selection, press `:` will give you  `:'<,'>`, `'<,'>` is the `[range]` part.

Then do the substitute like below **but note that this will affect the entire line(s)**:

```
:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g
```

If you would like to change `foo` to `bar` **only** in the visually selected area (i.e., character-wise or block-wise selection) then you'll have to use [the `\%V` atom](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25V):

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vfoo/bar/g
```

The article [Search and replace in a visual selection](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210402125037/https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection)) has much more useful info on the topic.

Comment: what's the normal range parameter? Does `:2,5s/foo/bar/g` mean from line2 to line 5?

Comment: Or use the shorter `*` as an abbreviation for `'<,'>`.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the scope to the visual *lines*, the `'<,'>` range does the job. For a characterwise or blockwise selection, this isn't sufficient, though. You need to modify the regexp or use the *vis.vim* plugin; otherwise, also characters outside the selection (but within the line(s)) will be affected, too.

Find the complete discussion on the Vim Tips Wiki: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Applying_substitutes_to_a_visual_block

---

**NOTE**: This answer is from 2012, and [the `\%V` atom](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25V) can now (4/2/2021) be used to restrict changes to **inside** the visual selection (character-wise or block-wise). See the article [Search and replace in a visual selection](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210402125037/https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection)), but the article above has also been updated since.