# vim: how to replace text in visual mode selection?

Tags: vim, replace, selection, mode

I've got a text file:

```
hello world ssh! 
this is your destiny 
Oh my goodness
```

In visual mode, I select from "world" to "my": I wish to change letter 's' into 'k' in my selection.

I definition cannot use line-mode because in that way the 3rd line's "goodness" will be changed.

So how to do this replacement in visual mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitue with the visual selection in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105399/how-to-substitue-with-the-visual-selection-in-vim)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To achieve the same in normal mode (after you've made a selection and escaped from it), use the `\%V` atom along with the `%` range modifier together in a substitute query

```
:%s/\%Vs/k/g
```

`:s/foo/bar` - a substitute query
`%` - makes sure it applies to all lines in the file
`\%V` - limits the range to the last visual mode selection (i.e. the one you get with `gv`)
`g` - a global flag which makes sure all occurrences will be affected (instea of the first one in each line, which is the default behavior)

More at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

Comment: `%` make sure it applies to all lines of last visual selection.

Comment: Do you mean `%` as in `%s` or `\%V`?

Comment: The first one denoting the range.

Comment: It makes range equal to entire file, check `:help range` for that. What effectively constrains the range to the selection is the \%V atom (`:help %\V`). `%s` just makes sure it checks for parts of that selection in **every** line of the file. Without this (with `s` alone) it would be unable to check more than one line.

Comment: You cannot make selection for separeted lines !!

Comment: How would you replace a string that contains forward slashes, like `/tmp/file`? When using `%s//<your-replacement-string>`, it becomes `<your-replacement-string>/tmp/file`

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\%V` to restrict the search to the visual selection:

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vs/k/g
```

See `:help \%V`

Comment: `'<,'>` is useless when using `\%V`

Comment: `'<,'>` is added automatically by Vim so it's best to show it in the example.

Comment: @Meninx what do you mean?
The above answer explained thoroughly at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection

Comment: @krzemian Exactly.